# Elasticsearch: Change permissions of old folder index to work with yum-installed elasticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I used a specific library that used an embedded version of elasticsearch. Now as we are growing, I want to start elasticsearch as a service.

I followed [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html#_yum_dnf) to install it using `yum` on a linux machine. I pointed ES to the new directory using

```
path:
    logs: /home/ec2-user/.searchindex/logs
    data: /home/ec2-user/.searchindex/data
```

When I start the service

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

I get a permission denied error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/.searchindex/logs/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
....
```

I guess this has to do with the folder permission, I changed folder permission using:

```
sudo chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch -R .searchindex
```

But that didn't help.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your user elasticsearch can't write in the logging folder : /home/ec2-user/.searchindex/logs

Check the permissions with `ls -l`

Set write permission with the `chmod` command :
e.g. : `sudo chmod -R u+wx .searchindex`

Comment: I used `chown` and that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because `.searchindex` is located in ec2-user directory which obviously is inaccessible by `elasticsearch` user created to manage the elasticsearch service.

Moving the folder to `/var/lib/elasticsearch` did the trick.